# NodeJS Variable hoisting

Tags: javascript, node.js, hoisting, replit

I just wonder how variable hoisting in NodeJS works. In the example below

```
console.log(name);
var name = "Rambou";
```

execution returns `undefined` which is correct since Hoisting works. `var name;` is being moved to the top like

```
var name;
console.log(name);
name = 'Rambou';
```

**The question is:** Why hoisting does not work for let and const? Both examples below return exception of an **undefined** variable.

```
console.log(name);
let name = "Rambou";
```

```
console.log(name);
const name = "Rambou";
```

> ReferenceError: name is not defined
>
> ```
> at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:13
> at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
> at Object.runInContext (vm.js:311:6)
> at evaluate (/run_dir/repl.js:133:14)
> at ReadStream.<anonymous> (/run_dir/repl.js:116:5)
> at ReadStream.emit (events.js:198:13)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
> at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
> at lazyFs.read (internal/fs/streams.js:181:12)
> ```

Execution has happened at **repl.it** platform.

Comment: @HassanImam could you provide a link of the javascript specification where I can read more about it? Are you referencing in ES5, ES6 or other?

Comment: `let` and `const` declarations remain uninitialized. However I believe technically they are hoisted. Check [this out](https://blog.bitsrc.io/hoisting-in-modern-javascript-let-const-and-var-b290405adfda)

Comment: Tagged question contains good explanation as well as good reference, do check out that.

Comment: @HassanImam you comment is wrong. `let` and `const` **are** hoisted [13.3.1Let and Const Declarations](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations) `[...]The variables are created when their containing Lexical Environment is instantiated but may not be accessed in any way until the variable’s LexicalBinding is evaluated[...]`. And as it is hoisted, this code: `let test = 4; function foo() {console.log(test); let test=5;} foo();` results in a ReferenceError.

Comment: I agree that the comment is wrong, all the variables and functions are hoisted but accessing the variables created with `let` and `const` in the `temporal dead zone` result in `ReferenceError`.